# How to delete the browser certificates for Automatically Automatic test depending of protractor

Tags: protractor, webbrowser-control

I am doing e2e test using protractor and I need to know how to force the browser to delete any certificates its in HTTPS/SSL in the chrome browser I mean.

Comment: webdriver-manager start --ignore_ssl true run this one while start webdriver

Comment: @SureshSalloju thank you even its too late hehe